# Dagger 2 scopes and multiple bounds

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

In Dagger 2 Android, I was really liking the new simplified API, but I now require a little bit of customisation and it's making my head hurt.

I have a very common scenario: an app with some activities and every dependency is injected.

I'll describe my current implementation first and the problem afterwards. Bear with me for a second, please.

I started by creating the regular `ActivitiesModule`

```
@Module
abstract class ActivitiesModule {
    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
    abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();

    // More activities here, all with the scope @PerActivity
}
```

and then my `MainActivityModule.java` (and all the other activity modules) look like this

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @Binds
    @ActivityContext
    @PerActivity
    abstract Context provideActivityContext(MainActivity mainActivity);

    @Binds
    @PerActivity
    abstract Activity provideActivity(MainActivity mainActivity);

    @Binds
    @PerActivity
    abstract MainMvpView provideView(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

This is perfect, because every time I needed the activity or context in a class, I could just do this, without tightly coupling my object to a specific activity.

```
@PerActivity
public class MainPresenter {
    private final MainMvpView view;

    @Inject
    MainPresenter(MainMvpView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

This is great, because I don't need to declare a `@Subcomponent` if I don't have to. **However**, now I want to inject a custom view into my `MainActivity` subcomponent, and I'm having issues going back to the old `dagger.android` way of doing things.

So far, I replaced the `ContributesAndroidInjector` with the old way, like this

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> 
bindMainActivityInjectorFactory(MainActivitySubcomponent.Builder builder);
```

and I created a new `MainActivitySubcomponent` that looks like this

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent
public interface MainActivitySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity> {}
}
```

The module pretty much stayed the same. The problem is that I'm getting lots of errors that say that `Activity` and `Context` are bound multiple times.

So my 2 questions are:

1. Is it not possible to have `@Binds` with `Activity` and `Context` if they are scoped so that I can keep things totally decoupled?
2. Is there an alternative to do view injections using the latest from `dagger.android`?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to add the module to `MainActivitySubcomponent` and make sure that the module is not added to your AppComponent directly (so that it is bound only in that subcomponent, not multiple times in a parent) If the error persists please include the full setup that leads to the error

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the end I managed to get it working by looking at the auto-generated classes and copying what they were doing. In the `ActivitiesModule` where I have all the `ContributesAndroidInjector` declarations and the new `@Binds @IntoMap @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)`, I added the subcomponent to the module annotation. It looks like this now `@Module(subcomponents = MainActivitySubcomponent.class)`.